# HTML/CSS How to format Text and have an Image floating next to it

Tags: html, css, image, formatting, css-float

Pretty rusty on my HTML and CSS skills, I've done this before at some point but forgotten how to do this.

I have text on the left side of the page, I want an image on the right side of this div next to it, floating there and not disturbing the text formatting.

```
Text Description.....
Description..........
Description..........                             Image Goes About Here
Description..........
Description..........
```

Does anyone know how to do this off the top of their head?  Thank you.

Comment: yeah, add `float: right;` to the css that targets the image. unless your markup is more complex, but since you didn't post any, nobody here has any idea.

Comment: For future reference, please post the code you need help with. We like to see attempts at what your trying to achieve, rather than just do it for you. Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy solution is to use display: inline-block to display information next to an image, without having to add inline css.

```
img, p {
   display: inline-block;

}


<img src="image.png" />
 <p>
 text left
 </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

for example
`<style type="text/css">`
 `#picture {`
 `float: right;`
 `}`
 `#text {`
 `margin-right: 110px;`
 `}`
`</style>`

edited

Comment: i'd highly recommend avoiding including styling information in your html document. the html is for content. css files are for styling layouts. much better to add a class so you can easily tweak the layout without having to modify the original html doc.

Answer (score 0):

use padding and float...

I.e.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="text" style="padding-right: <image-width+few px>">
     text text text
     text text text
  </div>
  <img src="<imagesrc" style= "float:right" />
</div>
```

padding so the text doesn't overlap with the image.
this should give you the desired effect.
After the image, add a div with clear:both to return to use all the dims of the div.